# When querying DateTime Fields from the DB, can I control the DateTimeKind?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, dapper

When I query a SqlServer database from C# which involves `DateTime` fields, the returned `System.DateTime` has `Kind==Unspecified` which is unsurprising as SqlServer `DateTime` type retains no timezone information.

I wondered if there's a way to automatically have these values read as local or universal, rather than manually convert them after reading the query results which introduces more possibility of mistakes when a field is missed.

Typical code looks like:

```
    using (var conn = ...)
    using (var command = ...)
    {
        conn.Open();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          DateTime dateField =  (DateTime)reader["date"];
          //dateField.Kind == Unspecified
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in way to do that, but you can easily create your own extension method for `SqlDataReader` and then call `reader.GetDateAsLocal("date")` and `reader.GetDateAsUtc("date")`.

Comment: When DateTime is stored in SQL server, the timezone information is not stored. So it's not available when you retrieve it. Either you can make sure that DateTime value is converted to UTC before it is stored in db or use DateTimeOffset to store DateTime values in Database.

Comment: SQL Server also has the `datetimeoffset` type, which uses the *same* space as `datetime` if you don't want milliseconds (`datetimeoffset2(0)`). Use `datetimeoffset` instead of `datetime` to avoid guessing. `Local` doesn't mean anything anyway - local to whom? The DB server, the web server, the browser? Even the offset want prevent all  problems - what happens if DST rules change? If that's a concern, store the IANA timezone as well and use eg NodaTime to handle dates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's all well and good but "change the database" is often not something within the developer's authority!

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dateField = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)reader["date"], DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

As its not persisted in the database you have to specify it on retrieval in your own code, there is no shortcut method in the DataReader although you could create an Extension method.

```
public static class Helper{
    public static DateTime GetDateTimeAsUtc(this IDataReader reader, string column){
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)reader[column], DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

and then call it

```
DateTime dateField = reader.GetDateTimeAsUtc("date");
```

Comment: This is a really nice pattern.  Thanks for codifying it.  +1.